# What is the name of this interface element?

Tags: interface

Does anyone know what the proper term is for this incremental counter thing?

BONUS: Is there a definitive guide you use to classify these elements? Thanks!
 [image]

Comment: According to the StackExchange Tour guide, this is the Voting UI.

Comment: If you are calling out the specific element from StackExchange, @Agnes points out what they call it. In more general terms, it could be seen as an over sized "Stepper" or "Spinner" or control.

Answer (score 1):

It's a sub-traditional object - often tied in with a drop-down menu or a hidden dropdown.  As far as I've experienced, it's called a **Picker** or a **Picker Control**.  I've seen it more commonly used in date pickers

See:
(Android) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

(Microsoft Desktop)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761726(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

(iOS - both Date Picker and individual Picker)https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Controls.html

Comment: User is not really *picking* anything here, so calling it a picker or picker control is incorrect in my opinion.

Comment: For this website's practical application of it, I agree  - but out of this particular context, I would still call the control a "Picker".  

You could technically (yes, splitting hairs here) say that you are picking whether you like or dislike something and the developers only gave you two choices.

When I am talking about controls I assume that I'm also going to be talking with individuals who may be implementing said control - if that were the case, most likely they'll know how to implement without thinking about it if I use their terms for a "thing".